# Safari, Yosemite: Where is "Reopen all windows from last session" stored?

Tags: macos, safari

Title wraps up the whole thing, but to elaborate I have an applescript that deletes Safari's history folder, bookmark folder, and a few other boot cache items, but quitting Safari, running the script, then re-opening Safari I can still choose "Reopen All windows from last session" and get the very last page from the site I was just at - where is this info stored? If my gf catches me looking at porn again I could be in hospital for a month or more!

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in `~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist`, where `~` is your home folder of course.

Comment: Yeah, that gets deleted in my script, in fact the script moves Bookmarks.plist to the desktop, deletes the whole contents of ~Library/Safari/ then moves Bookmarks.plist back into Safari folder, then emptys the trash. But opening up safari stills shows last session web page, must be something stored somewhere else too... I'd blow kisses but last time they got edited out...